# Commenting Standards C

Tags: c, comments

I work with a team called the Solar Jackets at Georgia Tech, and we have been having a "commenting crisis". We have many members that graduate, and leave behind comment-less code. I am looking to implement a commenting standard, so that this does not happen, and I need some suggestions to make sure I have all of my bases covered.

What I want is the following functionality:

- A consolidated place, where you can view every functions description,
  including includes, arguments, return types, and a general
  description of the code. (generated from the comments in the code)
- In the code itself, a line by line (or close to) description.

Is there any suggestions of what I may have left out? Are there are any programs that can automatically generate the code compilation? How could I make this easier on the programmers?

Comment: [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) ?

Comment: This is a bit late, but it might be helpful to mention that my company implemented a coding standard about a year ago, with excellent results. [CSI Commenting](http://standards.mousepawgames.com/csi.html). Most important aspect of this is **comment WHY, not WHAT**. "What" is apparent from reading the code, but "Why" is the harder thing to ascertain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what you describe reminds me of Doxygen. It has a format for commenting all entities in the code including functions, parameters, variables,...
It can be used to enforce everything is been documented by checking the warnings generated by Doxygen. It generates the complete document off of the source code in differents formats like HTML, Latex, PDF,...

Many IDEs know Doxygen tags and can be integrated with Doxygen to help developer on commenting the code.

here is an example of Doxygen comment:

```
/**
 * @brief This function does blah blah.
 * @param test blah blah parameter.
 * @return 0 if blah blah passed.
 */
uint32_t TestFunction( uint32_t test )
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Enforce good coding habits.  Variable names and method headers should be descriptive and focus specifically on the task they're doing.  For example, if you had a method to swap two elements, calling it `swap()` is sufficient.
- Use document generating tools such as [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).
- Feel encouraged to use other APIs such as the [Java 7 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) as a go-to guide for readability, and what to do (or not do).

I should probably stress that *too much* documentation can be extremely distracting.  Let the programmers - who are experts in what their software is doing - give a high-level overview for the sake of documentation.  If they want to, or must, then let them explain complicated or convoluted code on their own terms.

Answer (score 1):

Here at my new job, we try to avoid using comments at the maximum. The code should be self-documenting. Some small comments are allowed on tricky code, or bug fixes and the like, but day-to-day programming includes no comments at all.

We use code review sessions so all the team members get to read and study new code, and if it's not clean and easy to read, it's refactored. Usually, including local variables to name expressions, not reusing variables and adding #defines for constant literals do the job.

Comment: We do that to a large extent as well, but with many of our projects, progress is stop and go. We have Senior design groups that we have no control over, creating code and then disappearing at the end of the semester.

Answer (score 1):

A line-by-line commentary on the code sounds dire.

- You need a comment at the start of a function to identify what it does.

  - If the parameters etc are not obvious, they should be discussed.
  - Otherwise, it should be as brief as possible, preferably just one line.
  - If the function is complex, it may be appropriate to have a bigger comment; use judgement.
- You usually need a file header comment containing the company's or project's licence and copyright identification, and a note about the overall purpose of the file.
- You should document variables defined (which should mainly be `static` variables; you don't use globals, do you?).
- You might need to comment paragraphs of code within functions, preferably with short (one line) comments.
- Occasionally, you need to document the non-obvious or obscure (perhaps with a reference to the relevant bug report).
- You should seldom need tail-comments except on local variable definitions.

Otherwise, the code should very largely explain itself, rendering comments superfluous.

Note that comments that don't describe the current code are a nuisance.  Only yesterday, I removed a comment clearly added in 1990 – the date was in the comment – describing the status quo in 1990, when a particular function was simulating 'variable arguments'.  The code had long since been updated so that the function was treated as having 7 fixed arguments; the last four can be null when not needed.  So, the comment was no longer accurate, but a decade or more.  It went.  Why didn't anyone else notice it?  Probably because no-one else read that file for the first time without a mentor to guide them past the erroneous comment.  Or perhaps because the comment was too far enough removed from the function (there was a whole separate, albeit small, function between the comment and the function it mis-described).  So, 30 lines of (inaccurate) comment have finally gone to the bit-bucket in the sky.

Note, too, that what experts need and what novices need for the same piece of code may be quite different.  You have to make a judgement call on what level of commentary makes sense, but I'd recommend erring on the spartan side over essays, because when it comes time to modify the code, one of the two descriptions will not be properly maintained, and the odds are it will be the comments that are not maintained.  And misleading comments are more dire for novices than for experts!  So, make sure you can't get comments which are inaccurate by not having any avoidable comments.